# Генетический алгоритм на pascal

Tags: алгоритм, pascal, генетический-алгоритм

Требуется найти максимум функции F на заданном интервале [a, b) методом генетического алгоритма с точностью 1/16384. Размер начальной популяции = 10 (начальная популяция формируется случайным образом). Количество скрещиваемых особей и вероятность мутации особи вводятся с клавиатуры. В качестве критерия останова берется выполнение алгоритмом априорно заданного числа итераций без улучшения целевой функции; cелекция производится методом пропорционального отбора, а скрещивание - универсальным. Мутация выполняется реверсом битовой строки, начиная со случайно выбранного бита.

Код, уже написанный мной, приведён ниже (остается написать процедуру скрещивания, с которой уже и не знаю, что делать) (Free Pascal)

```
uses crt;

const
  a = 0;
  b = 4;
  N = 10;
  maxword = 65536;
  exitnum = 1024;
  T = 0.5;
  chance = 0.6;

type
  pop = array [1..N] of word;

var
  population: pop;
  i, number, useless, strong, count: integer;
  x1, x2: word;
  minx: real;
  c: char;
  control1, control2, exitcode: boolean;
  output: text;
  name: string;

function F( x: real ): real;
  begin
    F:= ( x - 2.1 ) * ( x - 1.5 ) * ( x - 0.33 ) * ( 1 - exp( x - 3.5 ) ) * cos( x );
  end;

function Change( x: word ): real;
  begin
    Change:= x * ( b - a ) / ( maxword - 1 );                                    //conversion word-number into number from [0;4)
  end;

procedure FormPopulation ( var mas: pop );
  var i: integer;
  begin
    randomize;
    for i:= 1 to N do
      mas[i]:= random( maxword );
  end;

procedure Sort( var mas: pop );                                                 //sort population by the meaning of function
  var
    i, j: integer;
    res: array [1..N] of real;
    r: real;
    x: word;
  begin
    for i:= 1 to N do
      res[i]:= F( Change( mas[i] ) );
    for i:= 1 to ( N - 1 ) do
      for j:= ( i + 1 ) to N do
        if res[j] < res[i] then begin
          r:= res[i];
          x:= mas[i];
          res[i]:= res[j];
          mas[i]:= mas[j];
          res[j]:= r;
          mas[j]:= x;
        end;
  end;

function Choose( mas: pop; k: integer ): word;                                  //chose random individual from population
  var i: integer;
  begin
    randomize;
    i:= random( k ) + 1;
    Choose:= mas[i];
  end;

function Binary( bit: integer ): word;                                          // counts 2^bit (to work with binary numbers)
  var k: word; i: integer;
  begin
    k:= 1;
    for i:= 1 to bit do k:= k * 2;
    Binary:= k;
  end;

function Get( x: word; bit: integer ): boolean;                                 //find the specific bit in binary form
  begin
    Get:= ( x and Binary( bit ) ) <> 0;
  end;

procedure Reverse( var x: word; bit: integer );                                 //reverse the binary form from the specific bit
  var
    mas: array [0..15] of boolean;
    i: integer;
  begin
    for i:= 0 to bit do begin
      mas[i]:= Get( x, i );
      if mas[i] then x:= x - Binary( i );
    end;
    for i:= bit downto 0 do begin
      if mas[i] then x:= x + Binary( bit - i );
    end;
  end;

procedure Mutate(var m: pop; posib: real);
    var
        mkoef, chance, i, j: integer;
        tmp: string;
    begin
        randomize;
        for i:= 1 to n do begin
            mkoef:= random(17);
            str(m[i], tmp);
            chance:= random(100) + 1;
            if (mkoef <> 0) and (chance <= posib * 100) then
                for j:= mkoef to 16 do
                    if tmp[j] = '1' then tmp[j]:= '0'
                        else tmp[j]:= '1';
            val(tmp, m[i]);
        end;
end;


procedure WriteToFile( var f1: text; mas: pop );
  var
    i, j: integer;
    k: real;
  begin
    writeln( f1, 'Population on ', number, ' iteration:' );
    writeln( f1, 'Bit values of arguments:' );
    for i:= 1 to N do begin
      for j:= 15 downto 0 do begin
        if Get( mas[i], j ) then write( f1, '1' )
        else write( f1, '0' );
      end;
      write( f1, ' ' );
    end;
    writeln( f1 );
    writeln( f1, 'Values of arguments:' );
    for i:= 1 to N do write( f1, Change( mas[i] ):1:5, ' ');
    writeln( f1 );
    writeln( f1, ' Current function values:' );
    for i:=1 to N do write( f1, F( Change( mas[i] ) ):1:5, ' ');
    writeln( f1 );
    writeln( f1 );
  end;

procedure WriteOnScreen(mas: pop );
  var i, j: integer;
  begin
    writeln( 'Population on ', number, ' iteration:' );
    writeln( 'Bit values of arguments:' );
    for i:= 1 to N do begin
      for j:= 15 downto 0 do begin
        if Get( mas[i], j ) then write( '1' )
        else write( '0' );
      end;
      write( ' ' );
    end;
    writeln;
    writeln( 'Values of arguments:' );
    for i:= 1 to N do write( Change( mas[i] ):1:5, ' ');
    writeln;
    writeln( ' Current function values:' );
    for i:=1 to N do write( F( Change( mas[i] ) ):1:5, ' ');
    writeln;
    writeln;
  end;

begin
  repeat
    control1:= false;
    control2:= false;
    exitcode:= true;
    clrscr;
    gotoxy( 1, 1 );
    write( 'This program counts minimun of the current function' );
    gotoxy( 1, 2 );
    write( 'Choose the program mode: 1) basic; 2) test' );
    repeat
      gotoxy( 1, 3 );
      c:= readkey;
    until ( c = '1' ) or ( c = '2' );
    write( c );
    if c = '2' then begin
      control1:= true;
      gotoxy( 1, 4 );
      writeln( 'Where do you want to write results: 1) in file; 2) on the screen' );
      repeat
        gotoxy( 1, 5 );
        c:= readkey;
      until ( c = '1' ) or ( c = '2' );
      write( c );
      if c = '1' then begin
        control2:= true;
        gotoxy( 1, 6 );
        write( 'Write the name of the output file: ' );
        readln( name );
        assign( output, name );
        rewrite( output );
      end;
    end;
    number:= 0;
    useless:= 0;
    FormPopulation( population );
    Sort( population );
    minx:= Change( population[1] );
    if control1 then
      if control2 then WriteToFile( output, population )
      else WriteOnScreen( population );
    repeat
      number:= number + 1;
      useless:= useless + 1;
      strong:= round( T * N );
      Mutate( population, chance );
      Sort( population );
      if ( F( Change( population[1] ) ) < F( minx ) ) or ( minx = 5 ) then begin
        minx:= Change( population[1] );
        useless:= 0;
      end;
      if control1 then
        if control2 then WriteToFile( output, population )
        else WriteOnScreen( population );
    until useless > exitnum;
    writeln;
    writeln( 'The current x: ', minx:1:6 );
    writeln( 'The minimum of the function: ', F( minx ):1:6 );
    writeln( 'The number of iterations: ', number );
    writeln( 'Do you want to repeat? Press "Enter" if yes and any other key if not' );
    c:= readkey;
    if ord( c ) = 13 then exitcode:= false;
    if control1 and control2 then close( output );
  until exitcode;
end.
```

Comment: Хорошо, а в чем состоит ваш вопрос?

Comment: Я прошу Вас написать мне процедуру скрещивания, ибо я уже не знаю, что с ней делать.

Comment: не актуально, сам написал, если надо, могу прикрепить код

Comment: А можно полный код программы? Мне еще только предстоит осилить такое, но хочется знать врага в лицо

Comment: Вы случайно не в МГУ учитесь? Чуть-чуть позже скину код полный

Comment: Нет, я не из МГУ, а почему должен быть?

Comment: А можете скинуть полностью рабочий код? У нас на ВМК только начался 2 семестр, задали задание такое же на генетические алгоритмы, ничего не объяснив. У всех свои функции и параметры выполнения, в моём случае: выполнение алгоритмом априорно заданного числа итераций; селекция: схема пропорционального отбора; скрещивание: одноточечное; мутация: реверс битовой строки, начиная со случайно выбранного байта. Хотелось бы разобраться на примере полностью работающего кода, заранее спасибо!